# Merge table cell in html view from phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to add rowspan/colspan from phpexcel view table in html ?

I have this table.

[image: A2 cell merged with A1]

I want to view that excel in html using PHPexcel View
but what i got is just like,

[image: Not merge]

The first column was not merged with the second column.

Does anyone know how to add rowspan in phpexcel view in html ?

My code is just like this

```
 $tmpfname = "./sampleData/member.xls";

    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet();
    $worksheet->mergeCells('A1:A3');
    $cell = $worksheet->getCell('A1');
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();


    echo '<table border="1"  >';
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {

         echo "<tr><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
          echo $worksheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('E'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('G'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('J'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('K'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('L'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('M'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('N'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('O'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use createWriter for creating HTML table from phpExcelObject.

```
$objWriter = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'HTML');
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$excelOutput = ob_get_clean();

echo $excelOutput;
```

Comment: can you explain to me, where can i load file excel with your code ?

Comment: your variable ``$excelObj`` is ``$phpExcelObject`` in this code.

Comment: did i must change my `$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname)` to `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelObj, 'HTML') ` ?

its give me an error like 

'Using $this when not in object context'

Comment: i cant use filetype HTML, but instead i use, Excel5, and it's worked. I could return value, but the table row and column did not imported to html, just some symbol and many other thing

Comment: Yes, You have to use static calls for your code. HTML file type? It's not file type. It's data export format. It'll not create a HTML file. After export you can change variable value with CSS. But if you are change excel data with PHP loops, It will always be depend the excel's merged cells. I don't know your file format and cell orders. You have to choose one. I hope you can handle it, good luck.